# Unexplained 'RRuntime Error' on rpy2.robjects.importr('package') where package is already installed

Tags: r, python-3.7, rpy2, install.packages

I'm new to rpy2 and I'm having an issue importing an already installed package. The package in question is "forecast". The following returns `TRUE`:

```
from rpy2 import robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr, isinstalled
robjects.r("install.packages('forecast')")
isinstalled("forecast")
```

When I then try to import the package, using `forecast = importr("forecast")`, I get:

```
RRuntimeError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\chswa\Workspace\BigData\01-Specreg\pyscript\src\scripts\Intrahour_CT_vol_forecast.py in 
      23 
      24 base = importr("base")
----> 25 forecast = importr("forecast")

~\Anaconda3\envs\BigDataEnv\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\packages.py in importr(name, lib_loc, robject_translations, signature_translation, suppress_messages, on_conflict, symbol_r2python, symbol_check_after, data)
    451     if _package_has_namespace(rname, 
    452                               _system_file(package = rname)):
--> 453         env = _get_namespace(rname)
    454         version = _get_namespace_version(rname)[0]
    455         exported_names = set(_get_namespace_exports(rname))

RRuntimeError:
```

with no explanation for the error.

This doesn't seem to be a problem when importing other packages, e.g. `aws.s3`. This:

```
robjects.r("install.packages('aws.s3')")
importr("aws.s3")
```

returns an object of type `rpy2.robjects.packages.InstalledSTPackage`, as expected.

How can I troubleshoot this? Does anybody know what the issue might be? By the way, I'm running Python through Anaconda, version 3.7.1, on Windows 10. rp2y is version 2.9.4.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

rpy2 2.9.x is rather old. This is likely because of API-breaking changes in R that occurred between when rpy2-2.9.4 was released and now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I installed rpy2 in a conda environment using `conda install rpy2` from the Anaconda console. That must be why I have an older version. Will try with a newer version!